# 0/1 Knapsack in Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, knapsack-problem

Am in on the right track for programming the knapsack problem in scheme? My program doesn't have to account for objects "values" , only their weights. The goal is to take the best combination of items so that I have approximately half of the weight in my bag.

```
(define (split-equip wlst)

 (define (sum lst)
  (define (sum-h accum lst1)
  (if (null? lst)
       (/ accum (length lst))
       (sum-h (+ (car lst1) accum) (cdr lst1))))
 (sum-h 0 lst))

(define (split-equip-h)
  (let ((target-w (/ (sum wlst) 2)))
```

I am tempted to write my program to output a list with all of the different combinations of weights possible and then traversing the list until I find the best set of weights, but not sure how to implement this.

Comment: Your idea is right; compute all combinations, and then find the one(s) closest to the (total weight)/2. There may be more than one combination that has the right weight, so the result should be a list of combinations. Try to do the combinations part first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is already your second attempt at this (the first question was deleted), I'll show you a solution in Racket. You should read it like pseudo-code and translate it into the Scheme variant you have been taught.

Disclaimer: I suck at these kind of exercises. That should be another reason for you to understand and reformulate this. But the results of my code still seem correct.

Here's the code:

```
#lang racket

(define (knapsack lst)

  (define half (/ (apply + lst) 2))   ; compute half of total
  (printf "list  : ~a\nhalf  : ~a\n" lst half)

  (define (combs lst1 (lst2 null))    ; compute all the combinations  
    (if (null? lst1)
        (if (null? lst2) 
            null
            (list (reverse lst2)))
        (append
         (combs (cdr lst1) lst2)      ; case 1 -> we don't carry the iten
         (combs (cdr lst1) (cons (car lst1) lst2)))))   ; case 2 -> we do

  (for/fold ((delta half) (res null)) ((c (in-list (combs lst)))) ; determine the best fit
    (let* ((sm (apply + c)) (newdelta (abs (- half sm))))
      (cond
        ((< newdelta delta) (values newdelta (list c)))
        ((= newdelta delta) (values    delta (cons c res)))
        (else               (values    delta res))))))

(time 
 (let-values (((delta res) (knapsack (cdr (range 0 24 3)))))
   (printf "result: ~a\ndelta : ~a\n" res delta)))
```

and here's what it says:

```
list  : (3 6 9 12 15 18 21)
half  : 42
result: ((3 6 12 21) (3 6 15 18) (3 9 12 18) (3 18 21) (6 9 12 15) (6 15 21) (9 12 21) (9 15 18))
delta : 0
cpu time: 6 real time: 5 gc time: 0
```

Hope this helps. Don't hesitate to ask questions if there's something you don't get!

Comment: Do you mind explaining the "for/fold" part of your answer? Does this piece just iterate through the list you made with the "combs" function setting delta to be newdelta if it is is closer to the target weight?

Comment: Yes exactly. delta and res are initialised (once), and then c is set successively to every combination from combs. The result is (values delta res).